# Reportlab text overlapping each other Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, reportlab

I am trying to work with 9 column csv data , some of which has links and big texts. I am using reportlab to export my data to pdf.

Here is my function:

```
def pdfGen(main_data_csv):
elements = []

# PDF Text
# PDF Text - Styles
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
styleNormal = styles['Normal']

# PDF Text - Content
line1 = 'LYIT MOBILE FORENSICS DIVISION'
line2 = 'Date: {}'.format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%y"))
line3 = 'Case Number: 10'
line4 = 'This forensic report on sms card data has been compiled by the forensic'
line5 = 'examiner in conclusion to the investigation into the RTA'
line6 = 'case which occurred on 23/01/2018.'

elements.append(Paragraph(line1, styleNormal))
elements.append(Paragraph(line2, styleNormal))
elements.append(Paragraph(line3, styleNormal))
elements.append(Spacer(inch, .25 * inch))
elements.append(Paragraph(line4, styleNormal))
elements.append(Paragraph(line5, styleNormal))
elements.append(Paragraph(line6, styleNormal))
elements.append(Spacer(inch, .25 * inch))

# PDF Table
# PDF Table - Styles
# [(start_column, start_row), (end_column, end_row)]
all_cells = [(0, 0), (-1, -1)]
header = [(0, 0), (-1, 0)]
column0 = [(0, 0), (0, -1)]
column1 = [(1, 0), (1, -1)]
column2 = [(2, 0), (2, -1)]
column3 = [(3, 0), (3, -1)]
column4 = [(4, 0), (4, -1)]
column5 = [(5, 0), (5, -1)]
column6 = [(6, 0), (6, -1)]
column7 = [(7, 0), (7, -1)]
column8 = [(8, 0), (8, -1)]
table_style = TableStyle([
    ('VALIGN', all_cells[0], all_cells[1], 'TOP'),
    ('LINEBELOW', header[0], header[1], 1, colors.black),
    ('ALIGN', column0[0], column0[1], 'LEFT'),
    ('ALIGN', column1[0], column1[1], 'LEFT'),
    ('ALIGN', column2[0], column2[1], 'LEFT'),
    ('ALIGN', column3[0], column3[1], 'RIGHT'),
    ('ALIGN', column4[0], column4[1], 'RIGHT'),
    ('ALIGN', column5[0], column5[1], 'LEFT'),
    ('ALIGN', column6[0], column6[1], 'RIGHT'),
    ('ALIGN', column7[0], column7[1], 'RIGHT'),
    ('ALIGN', column8[0], column8[1], 'RIGHT'),
])

# PDF Table - Column Widths
colWidths = [
    2.7 * cm,  # Column 0
    3.1 * cm,  # Column 1
    3.7 * cm,  # Column 2
    1.2 * cm,  # Column 3
    2.5 * cm,  # Column 4
    2 * cm,  # Column 5
    1.1 * cm,  # Column 6
    1.1 * cm,  # Column 7
    1.1 * cm,  # Column 8
]


# PDF Table - Strip '[]() and add word wrap to column 5
for index, row in enumerate(main_data_csv):
    for col, val in enumerate(row):
        if col != 5 or index == 0:
            main_data_csv[index][col] = val.strip("'[]()")
        else:
            main_data_csv[index][col] = Paragraph(val, styles['Normal'])

# Add table to elements
t = Table(main_data_csv, colWidths=colWidths )
t.setStyle(table_style)
elements.append(t)

# Generate PDF
archivo_pdf = SimpleDocTemplate(
    'SMS Data Report.pdf',
    pagesize=letter,
    rightMargin=40,
    leftMargin=40,
    topMargin=40,
    bottomMargin=28)
archivo_pdf.build(elements)
print('SMS Data Forensic Report Generated!')
```

I am getting the following overlapped rows as output.I am not so familiar with reporlab so having a hard time f9ixing it.Please help me fix this issue. Thanks a lot

[image]